# Keep vps process always!

Tags: xubuntu, vps, tmux

I bought a VPS, and I want to run a java instance. I want to keep this process always(after closing putty, after closing my PC)
I tried “tmux”. With tmux, the java program still running after closing the putty, but win I shut down my PC, server’s processes stops.
(P.S: I’m new in ubuntu)

Comment: What you say doesn't make sense. Once you close the connection, the connection is closed, and what you do on your local PC will not affect the remote VPS.

Comment: Read `man nohup` on how to start a process immune to disconnections (It calls them HANGUPS)

Comment: I closed the connection, the java program still ran, but when my pc hasn’t WI-FI connection, I opened putty and in the tmux process, I got “Killed”

Comment: Can you give me a URL to a tutoral of nohup?

Comment: Ok I found something on ibm.com